# Is there a Javascript ONC RPC library

Tags: javascript, rpc

Has anyone implemented [ONC RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) in Javascript? I need this to talk to a legacy server system and I was wondering if I could source the data directly rather than proxying through another server in Java or C.

Comment: I'm really not sure this qualifies as a candidate, but look at: ExtDirect http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm deep into javascript. specialy serversided with nodejs.

clientsided this is impossible because javascript in the browser can only speak http so you could only implement it serversided.

in case you would want to use javascript serversided, nodejs could do this without any external dependencies but sadly there has not been made a module for this special purpose yet. (as far as i seen)

if you would go this way i would recommend you to take a look at socket.io in order to have realtime communication between your browser and your server.
this way making a serversided proxy would not create a too huge overload.

Comment: +1  -i can easly tell the pain it gives, i just made a photo gallery of 20.000 stock and tried to show it on localnetwork by taking infos of each stock with RPC, after more than 10 people tried to reach it at the same time, problems started... For that reason i dont recommend this to anyone.